# Display ms word file in html using angular

Tags: angularjs, html

How can I display Microsoft Word file in HTML page using either Angular or JavaScript. Please suggest any libraries which provide this functionality.

Comment: Use I frame and pass the source of ur file

Comment: @Friyank I already tried it using I frame but it only opens up a dialog box to download the file. Never display it in browser. Please suggest any other approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what I found from my research is you can not display a word file using java script or angular, it only opens up a dialog box to download the file.

Here are some links backing my conclusion.
[display doc file in HTML link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816795/display-message-in-iframe-if-there-is-a-doc-file-which-cannot-be-displayed)
[display doc file in HTML link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-to-render-word-documentdoc-docx-in-browser-using-javascript)

As an alternate what you can do is convert word file to HTML and preview it in browser. Mammoth.JS is the best option for this.

Answer (score 11):

> No browsers currently have the code necessary to render Word
>   Documents, and as far as I know, there are no client-side libraries
>   that currently exist for rendering them either
>
> However, if you only need to display the Word Document, but don't need
>   to edit it, you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an  to
>   display a remotely hosted .doc/.docx.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

**Example:** 
[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbu2gsfm/)

However, if you'd rather have native support, in most, if not all browsers, I'd recommend resaving the `.doc/.docx` as a PDF file Those can also be independently rendered using PDF.js by Mozilla.

**Edit:**

Huge thanks to fatbotdesigns for posting the Microsoft Office 365 viewer in the comments.

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

**Live Examples:**

[Google Docs Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/7xr419yb/embedded/result/)

[Microsoft Office Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/embedded/result/)

Comment: reference and expand on an original source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957766/how-do-i-render-a-word-document-doc-docx-in-the-browser-using-javascript